# How to use poll in python 3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, tkinter, epoll

I am trying to display some data from /proc/stat file. Since this data constantly changes, I would like to update the values after every Interval (3 sec) on my screen. How do i achieve the same using poll() function?

Edit: I tried to achieve the same using threads and after. But I am not happy with the way it updates on my GUI. Below is my code for the same..

```
 def displayTab1(self):
            self.slabel1=ttk.Label(self.page1,text="  User Mode : ")
            self.slabel1.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=E,pady=15,padx=5)

            self.slabel2=ttk.Label(self.page1,text="  System Mode : ")
            self.slabel2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=E,pady=15,padx=5)

            self.slabel3=ttk.Label(self.page1,text="  Total CPU utilization : ")
            self.slabel3.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=E,pady=15,padx=5)
            self.slabel31=ttk.Label(self.page1,text="%")
            self.slabel31.grid(row=3,column=3,sticky=N+W,pady=15,padx=5)

            self.slabel4=ttk.Label(self.page1,text="   No: of Interrupts : ")
            self.slabel4.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=E,pady=15,padx=5)

            self.slabel5=ttk.Label(self.page1,text=" Context Switches : ")
            self.slabel5.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=E,pady=15,padx=5)

            self.slabel6=ttk.Label(self.page1,text=" Total Memory : ")
            self.slabel6.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=E,pady=15,padx=5)

            self.slabel7=ttk.Label(self.page1,text="  Available Memory : ")
            self.slabel7.grid(row=7,column=1,sticky=E,pady=15,padx=5)

            self.slabel8=ttk.Label(self.page1,text=" Memory Utilization: ")
            self.slabel8.grid(row=8,column=1,sticky=E,pady=15,padx=5)

            self.book.grid()

            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.tab1_Layout, args = ())
            t1.daemon = True
            t1.start()
```

```
    def tab1_Layout(self):
            self.MemFile = open('/proc/meminfo','r').readlines()
            for line in self.MemFile:
                    if line.startswith('MemTotal:'):
                            self.MemTotal = int(line.split()[1])
                    if line.startswith('MemAvailable:'):
                            self.MemAvail = int(line.split()[1])
                            break
            MemTotal=self.MemTotal
            MemAvail=self.MemAvail
            VarS=System.SystemInfo(self.usr_prev,self.sys_prev,self.idle_prev)
            self.usr_cur,self.sys_cur,self.idle_cur,usermode,sysmode,totalcpu,intr,ctxt,MemUtil= VarS.deltaTime()
            self.usrmodeVal = ttk.Label(self.page1,text = usermode)
            self.sysmodeVal = ttk.Label(self.page1,text = sysmode)
            self.totcpuVal = ttk.Label(self.page1,text = totalcpu)
            self.intrVal = ttk.Label(self.page1,text = intr)
            self.ctxtVal = ttk.Label(self.page1,text = ctxt)
            self.MemTotalVal = ttk.Label(self.page1,text = MemTotal)
            self.MemAvailVal = ttk.Label(self.page1,text = MemAvail)
            self.MemUtilVal = ttk.Label(self.page1,text = MemUtil)

            self.usrmodeVal.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
            self.sysmodeVal.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
            self.totcpuVal.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)

            self.intrVal.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
            self.ctxtVal.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
            self.MemTotalVal.grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
            self.MemAvailVal.grid(row=7,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
            self.MemUtilVal.grid(row=8,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)

            self.page1.after(I,self.tab1_Layout)
```

Comment: Infinite while loop with a `time.sleep` within it

Comment: Can you please give an example? I tried to get a syntax for the same, was unable to find something that fit mine on google..

Comment: show us the code you've tried, and we'll show you where you went wrong

Comment: I want to know how to use it. I was previously using thread and after for doing the same but wasn't happy with the way it was on GUI...

Comment: again, add your code to your post so that we can show you how to fix it

Comment: Added the existing code. What I want here is display the same data by using poll..

Comment: What do you mean by "poll"? There is no standard python command named "poll". More than one package has a "poll" method -- are you thinking about a specific library?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you keep creating more and more widgets. Don't do that. Create the widgets once, and then update them.

You also have the problem that you're using threads, and trying to use widget commands in more than one thread. Tkinter isn't thread safe, and interacting with widgets in two separate threads will yield unpredictable results.

Here's a working example, though I've removed a bunch of widgets to make the code easier to grasp:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.page1 = Frame(self)
        self.page1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.tab1_Layout()
        self.tab1_Update()

    def tab1_Update(self):
        self.MemFile = open('/proc/meminfo','r').readlines()
        self.MemTotal = self.MemAvail = 0
        for line in self.MemFile:
            if line.startswith('MemTotal:'):
                self.MemTotal = int(line.split()[1])
            if line.startswith('MemAvailable:'):
                self.MemAvail = int(line.split()[1])

        self.MemTotalVal.configure(text=self.MemTotal)
        self.MemAvailVal.configure(text=self.MemAvail)

        self.after(1000, self.tab1_Update)

    def tab1_Layout(self):
        self.MemTotalVal = ttk.Label(self.page1, width=10)
        self.MemAvailVal = ttk.Label(self.page1, width=10)

    self.MemTotalVal.grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)
    self.MemAvailVal.grid(row=7,column=2,sticky=W+E+N+S,padx=5,pady=5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried your way and it works just the way I want! Thanks a ton! Though the updated displays seems to be fine, I am however, not able to get the TEXT field on display. It seems to me that the value is configured   to be displayed in the same location (row/col) as the Label's text area. I am sure this is something silly, but I am unable to figure it out... The only other way that I can think off is again back to my old method... Kindly suggest what can I do to get both the Label as well as the data..

Comment: @Dee: I don't understand your question. I don't know what you mean by "the TEXT field". None of your code has anything labelled "TEXT", and you don't have any text widgets. f you want more things visible, add more widgets. This method doesn't limit you to any specific number of widgets -- add all you want.

Comment: I meant the Label's name/text is not visible as both the label and the value are configured to the same row/column. Hence, the Labels test is not visible on screen.
In my above example, for displayTab, I have several of them.. USER MODE, SYSTEM MODE,.. et cetera. When I try to configure like in your example, the text is lost/covered. I would like to update values for each of those labels.

Comment: I understood it all now! Thank you so much.. But I would still like to know how to use poll in place of after.